# Function returns incorrect value inside for loop (but correct value outside)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, struct

I'm trying to write a basic selection-sort program in C. From debugging, I can see that under the first for loop (// Swap the values), `selection(nums, size, i).index` returns the same value as `i`. However, if I call the `selection` function with the *exact same code* outside of the for loop, it will correctly return the index (of the number in the array with the smallest value and to the right of the given index).

How can I make `selection` return the correct value inside the for loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {

    int value;
    int index;

} sorted;

sorted selection(int integers[], int size, int idx);

int main(void) {

    int nums[] = {7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 6, 5};
    int size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);
    int temp;

    // Swap the values
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = selection(nums, size, i).value;
        nums[selection(nums, size, i).index] = temp;
    }

    // Print the array
    printf("[");
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (!(j == size - 1)) {
            printf("%i ", nums[j]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%i", nums[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

sorted selection(int arr[], int size, int start) {

    sorted smallest;

    for (int i = start; i < size; i++) {
        // If first element
        if (i == start) {
            smallest.value = arr[i];
            smallest.index = i;
        }

        // If smaller
        else if (arr[i] < smallest.value) {
            smallest.value = arr[i];
            smallest.index = i;
        }
    }

    return smallest;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `sorted` is near-wrothless in the first place. You have the array in *every* context in this program. Piggybacking the value *and* index in a `sorted` is worthless, since you can just get it from the array anyway once you have the index, which is all `selection` really needs to return.

Comment: Anyway, you should be calling `selection` *once* per iteration from you're loop in `main`. You're calling it twice, modifying `nums` in the interim. `nums[i] = ...` is modifying the array, thereby making the subsequent call on the next line return a different index, and thus breaking your algorithm.

Comment: I agree with @WhozCraig 100%. In addition to the answers you've already gotten, a simplification could look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/x8vn3rhv3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your version is failing is that you are calling `selection` a second time after starting to modify the array, when the index just needed to be retained after the first call.

The use of `sorted` and `selection` are, as @WhozCraig pointed out, completely unnecessary.  You are also passing `sorted` by value which is not the convention in C.

I've renamed the function to indicate its purpose.  This could be simplified to take only the elements right of the current index, but that would require some additional adjustments when handling the return value, so its a trade off.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int indexOfSmallest(int integers[], int size, int idx);

int main(void) {

    int nums[] = {7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 6, 5};
    int size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(int);
    int temp;

    // Swap the values
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = nums[i];
        int smallest = indexOfSmallest(nums, size, i);
        nums[i] = nums[smallest];
        nums[smallest] = temp;
    }

    // Print the array
    printf("[");
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (!(j == size - 1)) {
            printf("%i ", nums[j]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%i", nums[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int indexOfSmallest(int arr[], int size, int start) {

    int smallest = start;

    for (int i = start; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[smallest]) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }

    return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need change loop "// Swap the values"

```
// Swap the values
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sorted select = selection(nums, size, i);
    temp = nums[i];
    nums[i] = select.value;
    nums[select.index] = temp;
}
```